# Embedded Id is set to null

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B_Message")
public class Message implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "app-uuid")
    @Column(name = "MessageID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 36, columnDefinition = "uniqueIdentifier")
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "message")
    private Set<MessageReceiver> messageReceivers;
}
```

AND

```
@Entity
@Table(name="B_MessageReceiver")
public class MessageReceiver implements java.io.Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides( {
            @AttributeOverride(name="messageId", column=@Column(name="MessageID", nullable=false, length=36, columnDefinition = "uniqueIdentifier") ),
            @AttributeOverride(name="accountabilityId", column=@Column(name="AccID", nullable=false, length=36, columnDefinition = "uniqueIdentifier") ) } )
    private MessageReceiverId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="MessageID", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Message message;
}
```

AND

```
@Embeddable
public class MessageReceiverId implements java.io.Serializable {


    @Column(name = "MessageID", nullable = false, length = 36)
    private String messageId;


    @Column(name = "AccID", nullable = false, length = 36)
    private String accountabilityId;

}
```

And I use them in the following code

```
Message message = new Message();

Set<MessageReceiver> messageReceivers = new HashSet<MessageReceiver>();

MessageReceiver messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver();
MessageReceiverId messageReceiverId = new MessageReceiverId();
messageReceiverId.setAccountabilityId(this.accountabilityModel.getId());
messageReceiver.setMessage(message);
messageReceiver.setId(messageReceiverId);
messageReceivers.add(messageReceiver);

messageManager.saveMessage(message);
```

But when I want to merge the `Message` entity, the `messageId` of `MessageReceiverId` is not being set 
and sending null to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution as follows:

For the `message` property of the `MessageReceiver` entity I should have added `@MapsId` like:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="MessageID", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
@MapsId("messageId")
private Message message;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your embedded Id is a combination of two fields, `messageId` and `accountabilityId` but in your code you are only setting a value to the `accountabilityId`:

```
messageReceiverId.setAccountabilityId(this.accountabilityModel.getId());
```

You are missing to set the `messageId`, that's why you will have a `null` value for the `messageId`, because you need to set the two fields values so they won't be `null`, you just need to set a `messageId`too:

```
messageReceiverId.setMessageId(message.getId());/* the id value here */
```

**Edit:**

Save your `message` object in the database before assigning it and its id to the `messageReceiver`, then this line :

```
messageManager.saveMessage(message);
```

Whould be before this one:

```
messageReceiver.setMessage(message);
```

Then in the end, save the `messageReceiver` object in the database.

Comment: The problem is that the `message` is a newly created entity and not persisted yet, so it does not have any message Id automatically created for it. Please note that `messageId` should be created automatically and merge into other related entities.

Comment: So you have to save the message object in the database before you assign its id to the `messageReceiverId`.

Comment: Yes, because the `messageId` is generated automatically for me.